# ImageMap doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, imagemap

the image map function wont work in Internet Explorer 9, here is my Code:

My Image Tag:

```
 <img id="rechtsInMainNavBar" border ="0" src="res/images/rechts-mainNavBar.jpg" usemap="#mainnavigation">
```

My Map:

```
 <map id="mainnavigation" name="mainnavigation">
    <area href="index.html"  shape="rect" coords="3,4,95,72" class="openModal">
    <area shape="rect" coords="102,4,205,72" href="#InformationTab1" alt="Information" title="Information" class="openModal">
    <area shape="rect" coords="212,4,291,72" href="#ServiceTab1" alt="Service" title="Service" class="openModal">
    <area shape="rect" coords="294,4,373,72" href="#KontaktTab1" alt="Kontakt" title="Kontakt" class="openModal">
  </map>
```

Please help me, I have no idea... It works perfect in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Without having the fully-qualified URL to the image in question, this is difficult to test.

Comment: http://www.maybegeek.de/~so12xcss-grd/DreamweaverProject/res/images/rechts-mainNavBar.jpg

Thats the image

Comment: It seems to work fine in IE9 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/R6kxM/

Comment: ah it has something to do with my modal.css... because when i delete the link to the css it works fine.
thanks anyway!